# Windows Store TriageDump.dmp without debug information

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, windbg, debug-symbols, windows-store

Greetings people,

My [Windows Store game](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/ashers-maze/7dec0132-0d31-4682-a095-518f4383c5d8) has been released for more than three weeks now, and I started getting crash reports. I could download the **TriageDump.dmp** file and have it opened in **Visual Studio 2012**, but it did not help much, I am constantly getting "**No Debugging Information**" error message when I click on "**Debug with Native Only**":

[image]

Also, the tool-tip on my **Dashboard** shows no information of the crashing function (could "Unknown" here mean inlined function or lambda expressions in concurrent::task?):

[image]

I would like to believe that I have done everything the way it should be done, of course I may be wrong. Here are some additional information that might be helpful in finding the issue:

- It uses DirectX and written purely in C++ (without C# or XAML)
- Project setting: **C++\General\Debug Information Format** = Program Database (/Zi)
- Project setting: **Linker\Debugging\Generate Debug Info** = Yes (/DEBUG)
- The game is made up of two native modules: **Labyrinth.App.exe** and **Labyrinth.Core.dll**
- The generated **APPXUPLOAD** contains both **APPX** and **APPXSYM** files
- The **APPXSYM** file contains both **Labyrinth.App.pdb** and **Labyrinth.Core.pdb**
- I'm on **x64** development machine, and the triagedump.dmp is for **x86**
- I did click on "**Include public symbol files, if any, to enable crash analysis for the app**" when generating APPXUPLOAD file:

  [image]

Please let me know if you spotted the issue or suspected something that's wrong above. Thanks in advance for your help, guys! :)

Comment: At the moment, I'm having the same problem. Visual studio even produces some error message like this: "a required library for managed minidump debugging, 'mscordacwks.dll', version 'x.x.x.xxxxx' could not be located". Having located such dll in my local machine, it does exist, however in newer version

Comment: The very same problem here. MS had that working in the past though.

Answer (score 0):

The very same problem here. MS had that working in the past though.

Actually if you still have the **.appxsym** around you can easily extract the **.pdb** out of that. The appxsym is just a .zip file it seems.

You can load these pdbs then as symbols after loading the triagedump.dmp.